# Slim .htaccess static files issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

This is my structure:

```
- app
  - assets 
    - css
    - js
  - views
    index.html
- vendor
.htaccess
index.php
```

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(assets|bower_components|dist)/(.*)$ /app/$1/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^assets|bower_components|dist/.*$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]
```

My problem is that when I try to load:

```
/assets/css/style.css
```

from `index.html` it gives me `404`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: There is no style.css in your structure, is it?

Answer (score 2):

In .htaccess file change

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /assets
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the RewriteBase directive:

```
RewriteBase /
```

It so appears your project is not at the domain root.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteBase /
to
RewriteBase /assets
so that it works in .htaccess
```